# Unable to start WSO2 API Manager with Traffic Manager Profile

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am configuring the open-source version of WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0 in Distributed Setup. I have completed all the configurations, but when I try to start the API manager with Traffic Manager (or any other profile as a matter of fact), I am getting the below error.

```
 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occured while loading the Axis configuration from /wso2am-3.1.0/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:194) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.createNewConfigurationContext(CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.java:65) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:415) [org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:305) [org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118) [org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:973) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender cannot be found by axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportSenders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:713) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:125) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.populateAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:341) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:192) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender cannot be found by axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:261) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportSenders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:687) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:125) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.populateAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:341) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:192) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
        ... 8 more
```

Please let me know what changes I have to do in order to start the servers without any issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's complaining about the axis2.xml configuration not being correct. Did you alter this in any way?

Comment: No, I haven't altered it. When I start as all in one API Manager, it gets started without any issues. This issue occurs whenever I start with a specific profile (traffic manager profile in this case).

Comment: Does this error also occurs when running a previous version of the API manager?

Comment: Yes, it does occur in previous version as well when trying to start traffic manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try following these steps to avoid this error

1. Unzip a fresh distribution, do not start it,
2. Navigate to APIM-HOME/bin folder and run `sh profileSetup.sh -Dprofile=traffic-manager` This will remove files and configs not required for traffic manager
3. Next add your configuration in deployment.toml Only shared db will be needed for traffic manager and keystore configs
4. Start the server `sh wso2server.sh -Dprofile=traffic-manager`

Comment: Hi @dushansilva, I tried the same steps for api-publisher profile but the issue is still coming. Is there anything else to do for publisher profile?

Comment: @PrabakaranThodithotSembiyan are you still having the issue?

Comment: No @Jananath Banuka

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this document when you set up these distribute setup profiles.
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/next/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/product-profiles/#method-1-optimizing-before-starting-the-server